# JAVA on MacBook Air

Tags: java, macos, plugins

I use an application (I cannot show you because it's a back office) which I launch only on Chrome  which needs JAVA for work.

When I open a bash command, I tape java -version. I see "1.6.0_43".
But when I am using the web application, I have an error message which said 'Modul Java not present or needed'.

I don't understand because I am sure that not me the problem, I had installed the last version of JAVA.

Someone tells me that the problem on MAC is the Webstart which cancelled the launch of JAVA on web browser.

If U know something about this, Leave a comment :)))

Thx to all

Comment: If java enabled in your browser?

Comment: chrome://plugins/ - Check for Java(TM)

Comment: already done, all is good, java is installed. It's sure, but When I launch my apply, Chrome said me no ...

Answer (score 1):

> Chrome does not support Java 7. Java 7 runs only on 64-bit browsers and Chrome is a 32-bit browser.

The Mac OS forces you to use the Java 7 plugin (64-bit), but Chrome (32-bit) doesn't support it.  Use a different browser, go to http://java.com, and install the Java 7 plugin.

Comment: It's not easy. I have to use Chrome and not an other web browser for using my web application.

I have already tested to install java 7. It's the same problem, Chrome doesn't recognize JAVA

Comment: @Necko Then you're out of luck, because you cannot currently run Java applets in Chrome on Mac OS.

Comment: I have a macbook air, that doesn't work indeed. But a friend has a macbook pro, that's works ....

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty odd situation. I can confirm these problems. We have a java client that needs to be run under version 1.6. Normally, MacOS 10.8 does come with java version 1.7.

None the less, there is a java version 1.6 installed in your OS. I had to alter `/usr/bin/javaws` to the following

```
✗ ll /usr/bin/javaws
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  64 22 Feb 09:34 /usr/bin/javaws -> /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/MacOS/javaws
```

In case you get the message `Can not find message file: No such file or directory` when starting javaws: [have a look here at this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763646/starting-javaws-on-mac-os-fails-with-cannot-find-message-file)

Comment: `Normally, MacOS 10.8 does come with java version 1.7` - this isn't true. Java 7 does not come pre-installed on any Mac, as Apple has decided to cease official support for Java.

Comment: @Perception correct. I meant like there is no java 1.6 Installer for MacOS 10.8.

Comment: @Necko I meant that you may have to symlink `/usr/bin/javaws` to that executable. Make a backup of that file in any case!